# force https on login

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I'm trying to force https on the login page with 3.0.13-PL1. I set Server protocol to: https:// but that only changes http:// to https:// affects after the login. I do not want to use mod_rewrite on my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache 
If you are admin [Redirect Request to SSL](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)
But I think you aren't:

Apache Redirect HTTP to HTTPS using mod_rewrite
.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```